# Push x amount of data to object based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript

I have a function that counts something and return the value.

```
var c = containsObject("index", x);
```

Lets say C = 2;

Then i would like it to do something like this:

```
data.push({
    "date": getdate.toString(),
    "value": x["Index"],
    "value2": x["Index2"]
})
```

And if C = 8, then something like:

```
data.push({
    "date": getdate.toString(),
    "value": x["Index"],
    "value2": x["Index2"],
    "value3": x["Index3"],
    "value4": x["Index4"],
    "value5": x["Index5"],
    "value6": x["Index6"],
    "value7": x["Index7"],
    "value8": x["Index8"]
})
```

`x` is an array of data i get from my ajax call

What would the best way of doign this?

Comment: Use a for loop, and `x["Index" + i]`?

Comment: Does `x["Index"]` always return a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have tagged this with TypeScript, try annotating your types with index signatures to get rid of compile-time errors.

Try something like this:

```
let data: Array<any>;
let c = 8;

let x: {
    [key: string]: string
};

let obj: {
    [key: string]: string
} = {
        "date": getdate.toString()
    };

for (let i = 0; i < c; i++) {
    obj["value" + c.toString()] = x["index" + c.toString()];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would guess i would have to do something like `data.push(obj)` after. But if im correct, then it throws an error saying that data cannot read propperty of push

Comment: Is data typed as an `Array<T>`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `string-key` syntax for properties:

```
var _object={};
for(let i = 0;i<C;i++){
  let Cstr=C.toString();
  _object["value"+Cstr]=x["index"+Cstr];
}
data.push(_object);
```

Comment: Thanks, but if im using your code i get this typescript error, Index signature of object type implicitly has an 'any' type. Its on `_object["value" + Cstr]`

Comment: @TonyNielson at playground all it's ok, you enable 'any' type in your `config`? Instead of using any you can use `{}` type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bracket notation to do this.

```
const c = 3;
const object = {};
for (let i = 1; i <= c; i++) {
    object['value' + i] = x['index' + i];
}
```